Filesystem with encryption support
I need filesystem level encryption with the following features:

directory encryption.
being fast.
being based on passphrase.
has less overhead.
only the user who decrypt it can access and see the directory. EncFS has this ability, but it mounts another directory and it has disadvantage of limiting full path size.

What's your suggestion?


only the user who decrypt it can access and see the directory.

My initial answer was wrong, since ZFS and probably other file-level decryption technologies does indeed decrypt for all users with access once the passkey is loaded.
To encrypt and decrypt exclusively for the current user, you have to use user-space encryption like EncFS.
For Ubuntu, I would recommend you also take a look at SecureFS, which is a FUSE (filesystem-in-userspace) with native encryption.

The problem is that when I enter the passphrase, the data gets unlocked for all users, not only me.

It seems I was wrong - file-level encryption (including ZFS) does indeed decrypt for all users with access, once the passkey is loaded. It seems you need to use user-space encryption (like EncFS) in these situations.

Although it's an import from Windows, NTFS has this ability at file system level. You may encrypt a file or folder in a file system which others have access too, but they can't view your file's content. They may do so too. But they still may know the file's name. In Linux, specially with ZFS I need this capability. If not with ZFS, please introduce some Linux file system with this support. Thank you.
